# What is the correct way to install addons with Kubernetes 1.1?

Tags: kubernetes, coreos

What is the correct way to install [addons](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/release-1.1/cluster/addons) with Kubernetes 1.1? The [docs](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/release-1.1/cluster/addons) aren't as clear as I'd like on this subject; they seem to imply that one should copy addons' yaml files to /etc/kubernetes/addons on master nodes, but I have tried this and nothing happens.

Additionally, for added confusion, the docs imply that addons are bundled with Kubernetes:

> So the only persistent way to make changes in add-ons is to update the manifests on the master server. But still, users are discouraged to do it on their own - they should rather wait for a new release of Kubernetes that will also contain new versions of add-ons.

So, how should I really install addons, f.ex. [cluster-loadbalancing](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/release-1.1/cluster/addons/cluster-loadbalancing), with Kubernetes 1.1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ... they seem to imply that one should copy addons' yaml files to /etc/kubernetes/addons on master nodes, but I have tried this and nothing happens.

This is only true if you are using one of the salt-based installation mechanisms.

> So, how should I really install addons, f.ex. cluster-loadbalancing, with Kubernetes 1.1?

Most of the add-ons can be installed by just running `kubectl create -f` against the replication controller and service files for the add-on. You need to create the `kube-system` namespace first if you haven't already, and some of the add-ons (like [dns](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/addons/dns/skydns-rc.yaml.in)) require you to fill in a few values in a jinja template that would otherwise be handled by salt.

Comment: A few example commands/scripts would be helpful.  This is too high level, and still doesn't show me how to do it.  Run `kubectl create -f` plus what?  What do I need to run, install, download, copy, etc... before I run `kubectl create -f`?  Docs and search results are not clear.

Comment: Are you still using Kubernetes 1.1? ;)

Comment: Client 1.3.0.  Server 1.4.3.  According to `kubectl version`

Comment: The addons can be found in directories underneath https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/saltbase/salt. As I said in the answer, some of them are templated (like https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/saltbase/salt/etcd/etcd.manifest) and others can just be run as-is.

Comment: By the way, we will be working on better add-on management as part of the cluster lifecycle work for the upcoming Kubernetes 1.7 release. So this should be much better in a few months.