# How to install kube-dns on minikube?

Tags: kubernetes

I've looked at [How does one install the kube-dns addon for minikube?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43152190/how-does-one-install-the-kube-dns-addon-for-minikube) but the issue is that in that question, the addon is installed. However when I write

`minikube addons list`

I get the following:

`- addon-manager: enabled
- dashboard: enabled
- default-storageclass: enabled
- efk: disabled
- freshpod: disabled
- gvisor: disabled
- heapster: disabled
- ingress: disabled
- logviewer: disabled
- metrics-server: disabled
- nvidia-driver-installer: disabled
- nvidia-gpu-device-plugin: disabled
- registry: disabled
- registry-creds: disabled
- storage-provisioner: enabled
- storage-provisioner-gluster: disabled`

none of which is kube-dns. Can't find instructions anywhere as it's supposed to be there by default, so what have I missed?

**EDIT** This is minikube v1.0.1 running on Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 5):

The StackOverflow case which you are referring to was in 2017 so it's bit outdated.

According to [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-custom-nameservers/#introduction) CoreDNS is recommended DNS server which replaced kube-dns. There was a transitional period when both KubeDNS and CoreDNS were deployed parallel, however in latest version only CoreDNS is deployed.

As default `Minikube` is creating 2 pods with CoreDNS. To verify execute:

```
$ kubectl get pods -n kube-system
NAME                               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
coredns-5c98db65d4-g4vs2           1/1     Running   1          20m
coredns-5c98db65d4-k4s7v           1/1     Running   1          20m
etcd-minikube                      1/1     Running   0          19m
kube-addon-manager-minikube        1/1     Running   0          20m
kube-apiserver-minikube            1/1     Running   0          19m
kube-controller-manager-minikube   1/1     Running   0          19m
kube-proxy-thbv5                   1/1     Running   0          20m
kube-scheduler-minikube            1/1     Running   0          19m
storage-provisioner                1/1     Running   0          20m
```

You can also see that there is CoreDNS deployment.

```
$ kubectl get deployments coredns -n kube-system
NAME      READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
coredns   2/2     2            2           37m
```

[Here](https://coredns.io/2018/11/27/cluster-dns-coredns-vs-kube-dns/) you can find comparison between both DNS.

So in short, you did not miss anything. CoreDNS is deployed as default during `minikube start`.